# Bootstrap collapse with change data in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

[image]This is my table code and data view but problem is when i click particular view data show same, not change...Like I click first row, its show data but when i click second row same data show, how can i change data view in foreach loop? I am little bit stuck here

```html
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm  table table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="th-sm">Sport Id</th>
     <th class="th-sm">Gender</th>
     <th class="th-sm">Location</th>
     <th class="th-sm">Country</th>
     <th class="th-sm">State</th>
     <th class="th-sm">City</th>
     <th class="th-sm">Action</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   @foreach ($challenges as $challenge)
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
                  <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_location}}</td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_country_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_state_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$challenge->c_city_id}}</td>
       
     <div colspan="12" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> 
         sport{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}
gender{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}
location{{$challenge->c_location}}
country{{$challenge->c_country_id}}
state{{$challenge->c_state_id}}
city{{$challenge->c_city_id}}
date{{$challenge->c_date}}
desc{{$challenge->c_desc}}
time{{$challenge->c_time}}
invite{{$challenge->c_invite}}
refree{{$challenge->c_refree_id}}</div>
  
         <td><a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
           <a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></a>
           
           </td>
         </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>sport_id
      </th>
      <th>gender_id
      </th>
      <th>location
      </th>
      <th>country
      </th>
      <th>state
      </th>
      <th>city
      </th>
      <th>action
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the `$challenges` variable to see what you are receiving?

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> object(App\Challenge)#340 (26) { ["guarded":protected]=> array(0) { } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> string(10)

Comment: I think you are not understand my question....In foreach loop data give perfect but i want to when button view click data show deeply, wait i put image inquestion -@sebasaenz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you gives same `id`  in `data-target` and `id` attribute in collapse div change div id with every new row

```php
@foreach ($challenges as $key=>$challenge)
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{$key}}" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_location}}</td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_country_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_state_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$challenge->c_city_id}}</td>

        <div colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo{{$key}}"> 
                sport{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}
                gender{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}
                location{{$challenge->c_location}}
                country{{$challenge->c_country_id}}
                state{{$challenge->c_state_id}}
                city{{$challenge->c_city_id}}
                date{{$challenge->c_date}}
                desc{{$challenge->c_desc}}
                time{{$challenge->c_time}}
                invite{{$challenge->c_invite}}
                refree{{$challenge->c_refree_id}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <td><a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
            <a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you give each `element` a same id and it doesn't work so, you should write your `code` like below:

```
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm  table table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Sport Id</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Gender</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Location</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Country</th>
            <th class="th-sm">State</th>
            <th class="th-sm">City</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach ($challenges as $challenge)
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{$challenge->id}}" class="accordion-toggle">
                      <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_location}}</td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_country_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_state_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$challenge->c_city_id}}</td>

            <div colspan="12" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body 
     collapse" id="demo{{$challenge->id}}"> 
                sport{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}
    gender{{$challenge->c_gender_id}}
    location{{$challenge->c_location}}
    country{{$challenge->c_country_id}}
    state{{$challenge->c_state_id}}
    city{{$challenge->c_city_id}}
    date{{$challenge->c_date}}
    desc{{$challenge->c_desc}}
    time{{$challenge->c_time}}
    invite{{$challenge->c_invite}}
    refree{{$challenge->c_refree_id}}</div>

                <td><a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
               <a rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon table-action remove" href="javascript:void(0)" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="ti-close"></i></a>

               </td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>sport_id
          </th>
          <th>gender_id
          </th>
          <th>location
          </th>
          <th>country
          </th>
          <th>state
          </th>
          <th>city
          </th>
          <th>action
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```